# Feeds Import won't import all CSV items

Tags: drupal, csv, drupal-nodes

I've set up a feeds importer on my site.  It reads a csv file and imports the items to the site.  Then, it creates a node for each line.  It works well, except it never imports all the items from the file.  This is the case if I have 10, 50, or 300 items in the file.

I included a screenshot below.  The arrows show the notice that 35 nodes were created, then below, under Status, that 28 nodes were created.  Usually the items that weren't created are duplicates of items successfully imported in the batch.  However, some of the unimported nodes are not duplicates.

Does anyone have any input about this?  I can't seem to find any place that references this type of problem/mistake.

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

What are you using to generate your CSV file? If it's data that has been exported from a common app like Excel or Calc then it is probably fine, but if you're using CSV that has been exported from a custom app then it could have weird line endings (windows, unix and mac all have different ways of representing line endings in text files) or inconsistent field separators, or strings that are not surrounded by double quotes (so data in the field gets misinterpreted as a line ending or field separator), or or or.... anything. There is no standard for CSV.

Try importing your CSV file into Excel or Calc. Can you get it into a spreadsheet properly? If so, export that spreadsheet as a new CSV and see if that can be imported using the Feeds module.